# python 3.4.2 OSERROR: ERRNO 22 when using open to write to multiple files

Tags: python

hello im trying to write a game about having a village and keep it alive for 100 days but
 while writing the save system i came across an error this is my code:

```
filename = input("name of file: ").strip()  
filename = '"'+filename+'"'  
os.system("md "+filename)  
filename = filename.replace('"',"")  
file = open(filename+"\population.txt","w")  
file.write(str(population))  
file.close()  
file = open(filename+"\name.txt","w")  
file.write(str(name))  
file.close()  
file = open(filename+"\days.txt","w")  
file.write(str(days))  
file.close()  
file = open(filename+"\food.txt","w")  
file.write(str(food))  
file.close()  
file = open(filename+"\hours.txt","w")  
file.write(str(hours))  
file.close()  
file = open(filename+"\villagerskilled.txt","w")  
file.write(str(villagerskilled))  
file.close()
```

the population one works but when it gets to name it gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
file 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\survivor village.py', line 147 in <module>  
file = open(filename+"\name.txt","w")  
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "test\name.txt"
```

Comment: The reason your formatting didn't work is that you need to leave a blank line before and after code blocks. I've fixed it for you.

Comment: A few side notes: This code is crying out for a loop instead of repeating the exact same 3 lines of code 6 times, varying only in one string. Also, look at the methods in the `os` module; `os.mkdir` makes your `system` call unnecessary, and all the problems that go with it (like needing to quote `filename`—and your solution to that isn't very robust), and `os.path.join` would eliminate the possibility of the bug you ran into here. And if you do need to execute other programs, use `subprocess`, not `system` (which also eliminates the need for quoting).

Answer (score 1):

This is because `"\n"` is a new line.  Try `"\\n"` or `r"\n"` and this should solve your problem.  Also python accepts forward slashes `"/"` for paths on Windows, so it is probably safer to use those.

Read about escape characters [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm)

Also, it is generally bad form to name a variable "file" because `file()` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) in python.

Comment: thank you i added the extra backslash and it worked but i didnt know forward slashes worked

Comment: By the way, `file` isn't a built-in function in Python 3. And even in 2.x, it's a function that's rarely used (it was added in 2.2 for completeness, when most of the built-in types became classes and therefore usable as constructors, and its use was specifically recommended against from the beginning), and the docs have variables named `file` all over the place. It can occasionally be useful to test, e.g., `isinstance(f, file)`, so maybe better safe than sorry, but it's not the same as calling a variable `list` or `str`.

Comment: You should use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to concatenate path components.